# java threads and main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

what's the best way to make main thread to wait until all threads are finished?

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   Thread t=new Thread();
   t.start();

}

//wait for all threads to finish
```

Comment: use `Thread.join()`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a list and wait for the all.

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    Thread t=new Thread();
    t.start();
    threads.add(t);
}

for(Thread t: threads) t.join();
```

However using an ExecutorService can be a more elegant way to handle a pool of threads.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   es.submit(new Task(n));
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   Thread t=new Thread();
   threads.add(t);
   t.start();

}


for(Thread t:threads){
t.join();
}
```

Comment: this works, interestingly I made the mistake earlier by making t.start();t.join() in the same code block.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `thread.join( )`;.

It is also answered here already. Have a look.

- [Java - Wait for multiple threads to complete.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523050/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-variable-number-of-threads-to-finish-to-move-on-wit)
- [Java - How to wait for all threads to finish ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/java-how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish)

**Example :**

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
  String name; // name of thread

  Thread t;

  MyThread(String threadname) {
    name = threadname;
    t = new Thread(this, name);
    System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
    t.start();
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
  }
}

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyThread ob1 = new MyThread("One");
    MyThread ob2 = new MyThread("Two");
    MyThread ob3 = new MyThread("Three");

    System.out.println("Thread One is alive: " + ob1.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: " + ob2.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: " + ob3.t.isAlive());

    try {
      System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
      ob1.t.join();
      ob2.t.join();
      ob3.t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
    }

    System.out.println("Thread One is alive: " + ob1.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: " + ob2.t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: " + ob3.t.isAlive());

    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
  }
}
```

---

Although the question is tagged under "java", it can be also done in C# in following ways

- [C#: Waiting for all threads to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263116/c-waiting-for-all-threads-to-complete)
- [Wait for worker threads to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378767/wait-for-all-worker-threads-to-end)

Answer (score 0):

I think for your requirement the best solution is the **CyclicBarrier** 
look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

or

[at this example](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/java-barrier)

Comment: Your API link is to an old version of Java.  Use Java 6 instead.

Comment: Sorry http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CountDOwnLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

```
CountDownLatch lat = new CountDownLatch(noOfTasks);

ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

while(...) {

  exec.execute(new MyTask());

}


try {

  lat.await();

} 
catch (InterruptedException E) {

 //

}
```

and within your task 
(enclose in try / finally)

```
lat.countDown();
```