# Waiting for all threads to end

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have some code that I would like to use for device discovery on a network.
It simply pings any ip address on said network and if it gets an answer, adds the address in a list.

Code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    //do stuff to get subnetmask and local address
    //succession of for loop to increment ip address
    {
        PingAsync(ip_address);
    }

    //here I display the list of addresses that answered the ping
    //first Readline() is to manually wait for threads to end so the list isn't empty
    Console.Readline()
    Console.WriteLine("List of all devices found :\n");
    ipList.ForEach(delegate (string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t=> {str}");
        });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

```
private static void PingAsync(IPAddress address)
{
    AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    //items are added to ipList in PingCompletedCallback()
    pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

    string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    int timeout = 1200;

    PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);

    pingSender.SendAsync(address, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);
}
```

In the PingCompletedCallback method, I add items to a list that will be displayed in the main

```
private static void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Program prog = new Program();

    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping failed !");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }

    if(e.Error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping failed !");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());

        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }

    PingReply reply = e.Reply;

    if(reply.Status.ToString().Equals("Success", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
    //If the ping succeeds add the address to a list
        ipList.Add(reply.Address.ToString());
    }

    ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
}
```

The code works fine at discovering devices, only issue is with the list of addresses. If I don't manually wait for all threads to end it will appear empty.

According these posts [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280723/c-sharp-threading-lock-confusion) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221226/how-to-wait-for-the-thread-to-end-before-continuing-with-the-program) and some other, using Thread.join or Task.Waitall are the way to go. However, unlike them I am not creating threads myself but letting SendAsync() create its own thread.

Also, I can't change PingAsync() to make it await SendAsync() since it returns void.

I would like to know you would go about waiting for threads to end before printing/using the ipList.

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. However you are probably better off using the more modern `SendPingAsync ` then awaiting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of this code can be replaced with [Ping.SendPingAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=net-5.0#definition) :

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

   using var pingSender = new Ping();
   var options = new PingOptions(64, true);
   var reply=await pingSender.SendPingAsync(address,1200,options)
   if(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

**Concurrent Requests - One sender per request**

`SendPingAsync` can't be called multiple times to send multiple requests from a single sender. Doing so throws an InvalidOperationException.

One solution is to create and use a separate sender per call :

```
async Task<Reply> PingAsync(IPAddress address)
{
    using var pingSender = new Ping();
   var options = new PingOptions(64, true);
   var reply=await pingSender.SendPingAsync(address,1200,options)
}
```

Combined with LINQ, it's possible to start multiple pings concurrently and collect the results:

```
var addresses=new List<IPAddress>();
...
//Create the tasks with LINQ
var tasks=addresses.Select(address=>PingAsync(address))
                   .ToArray();
//And wait for all of them to complete
var replies=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

//Get the successful pings:
var successes=replies.Where(reply=>reply.Status==IPStatus.Success)
                     .Select(reply=>reply.Address.ToString())
                     .ToArray();
```

The first LINQ query will call `PingAsync` for every address and returns the `Task<Reply>` object returned by each call:

```
var tasks=addresses.Select(address=>PingAsync(address))
                   .ToArray();
```

The query is actually evaluated when `ToArray()` is called. All ping requests will start at the same time.

The next call awaits all of them to complete :

```
var replies=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

And finally, the last LINQ query retrieves the IPs of the successful pings:

```
var successes=replies.Where(reply=>reply.Status==IPStatus.Success)
                     .Select(reply=>reply.Address.ToString())
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. However, the first LINQ query throws an InvalidOperationException : "asynchronous call already running" due to pingSender.SendPingAsync(). It says I should wait for the process to end or terminate it before starting another one.

Comment: @FrougeurPro duh, that's what I get for not reading the small print. It's still possible to make concurrent requests, but that would require using multiple `PingSender` instances

Comment: @FrougeurPro I modified the code to use a different sender per request

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you again for your work.